# Значение вписанное в input добавилось в список ul

Tags: javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    <input name="text">
    <input type="submit" onclick="AddAChild();">
    <ul id=conteiner>
        <li>first</li>
        <li>second</li>
        <li>third</li>
    </ul>
    <script>
        function AddAChild() {
            var newEvent = document.createElement("li");
            newEvent.innerHTML = "getElementById(txt)";
            var container = document.getElementById("conteiner");
            container.appendChild(newEvent);
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Значение вписанное в input добавилось в список ul

Вот так:

```js
function AddAChild() {
  var newEvent = document.createElement("li");
  var container = document.getElementById("container");
  var inpt = document.querySelector('.inpt'); // input
  newEvent.innerText = inpt.value // Присвоить текст
  container.appendChild(newEvent);
  inpt.value = ''; // Очистить поле
}
```

```html
<input name="text" class="inpt">
<input type="submit" onclick="AddAChild();">
<ul id="container">
  <li>first</li>
  <li>second</li>
  <li>third</li>
</ul>
```